# How do I say "it made the hair on my neck stand up" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say

> It made the hair on my neck stand up

in Spanish? I'd like to say it in this context:

> The horror film was so scary that it made hair in my neck stand up.

Comment: -1, this is no translation service. Moreover this is cross posted from http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8952/how-do-i-say-it-made-the-hair-on-my-neck-stand-up-in-german which you didin't even bother to format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La película de terror daba tanto miedo que *me puso los pelos de punta*.

Comment: Otra alternativa: *me puso la piel de gallina*.

Answer (score 3):

There is some similar expressions in Spanish:

> Poner los pelos de punta
>
> Poner la piel de gallina

So in the sentence you gave it will be something like:

> La película de terror daba tanto miedo que me puso los pelos de punta.
>
> La película era tan terrorífica que hizo que se me pusiera la piel de gallina.